A clinic vaccinates 500 people each day and records the number of people having side effects on 5 randomly chosen days.
The vaccine produces a side effect with probability $p\in[0,1]$.

What is the probability that number of people who developed side effects on the 5 observed days are 10,15,0,20,25?
Find $p$ which maximizes the probability obtained above,
Based on the value of this $p$ what is the expected number of people who will develop side effects each day?

Ans: I think answer of the first part should be $$^{500}C_{10}p^{10}(1-p)^{490}\cdot ^{500}C_{15}p^{15}(1-p)^{485}\cdot (1-p)^{500}\cdot ^{500}C_{20}p^{20}(1-p)^{480}\cdot ^{500}C_{25}p^{25}(1-p)^{475}   $$ which can be written as $$ Ap^{70}(1-p)^{2430}  $$ where $A$ is a positive integer.
For the second part, we let $$f(p)= Ap^{70}(1-p)^{2430} $$ Then $$f'(p)=70Ap^{69}(1-p)^{2430}-2430Ap^{70}(1-p)^{2429} $$
Thus $f'(p)=0$ gives $$7(1-p)-243p=0  \implies p=\frac{7}{250} $$
For the third part, we need to evaluate $$\sum_{n=0}^{500} n\cdot ^{500}C_n p^n(1-p)^{500-n}  $$ for the above obtained value of $p$.
It'll be really helpful if someone can check if this is correct and also mention if there is any better way to do this.

What you have is correct, and for the first two parts there is not really a better way (unless you recognize that the second part is the same as finding the mode of a beta distribution, which can be looked up). For the last part, you don't have to compute the sum directly, as it is just the mean of a binomial distribution (which hopefully you have a formula for).

Thanks. For the third part, I see it's the mean of a binomial distribution , so I can just evaluate that by $np$ with $n=500$ and $p=7/250$.

@user2661923:they are recording the number out of $500$ that were vaccinated that day that develop side effects.  As a class problem you are clearly supposed to assume that the events of each person developing side effects are independent.  Why should one person developing side effects change the probability of another person.  In real life there may well be correlations because individuals from the same family come in together, but we ignore those.

@RossMillikan After reading your comment, and then reviewing the posted question, I realize that I mis-read the original problem.  So, I have deleted my previous comment.  My blind-spot/mistake was in assuming that you have $~500~$ people total, and each day you vaccinate the same $~500~$ people.  In retrospect, my assumption actually makes no sense.

I think the first part needs slight modification. Considering 10,15,0,20,25 people having side effects can come up in ${}_5 \mathrm{ P }_5$ ways, the first needs to be multiplied by 5!
